# Waiting for a response from another Process

Tags: java, multithreading, server, command-line-interface

So, to shorten this up, I'm building a script which should control a PHP server (aimed at Laravel). This all works fine so far.

```
public void run()
{
    //All the variables I'm about to initialize above synchronized (this) are dummy
    //variables, just so you know what they are. Their real location are the base
    //class.
        Process process = null;
        int port = 8888;
        String path = "C:/xampp/htdocs/some-laravel-server/public";
        boolean on = true;
    synchronized (this) 
    {
        //Turning on the server
        try {
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("php -S localhost:" + port + " -t " + path);
            System.out.println("Server running on localhost:" + port);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        //Waiting until another method (which switches var 'on' to false) to notify();
        while(on && process != null)
        {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
        //Turning off the server
        process.destroy();
        System.out.println("Server stopped");
        
        //resetting
        on = true;
        process = null;
    }
}
```

Now this `process` is a PHP `CLI` process. Whenever someone actually connects to the server, it sends out some message about the user/connection. My question is can I open another thread with `process`, which would, basically, give me a string (that I could use later) whenever the `CLI` actually sends out something?

For instance:

When a user connects to the server the CLI will respond with:

> [Mon Nov 23 22:00:00 2015] ::1:1234 [302]: /
>
> [Mon Nov 23 22:00:01 2015] ::1:1234 [200]: /somepage

Now can I get those 2 strings somehow within a Java program (using the Process object, or some other method)?

Thanks!

Comment: Use a `ProcessBuilder` to start with... And see the javadoc for `ProcessBuilder.Redirect` as well.

Comment: @fge Alright, will do, thanks!